# Gradient on sub menu with the same colors as on main menu

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have a menu line with gradient on a background. I want to style sub menu elements same as main menu, so gradients colors match. Also when page width is changed, colors are updated.

For example when Item #1 has gradient red->white, so the sub menu has the same. Next one Item #2 has gradient white->pink, so the sub menu has the same... and so on

Is there any way to do it with CSS only?

```
<style>
ul > li {display: block; float: left; margin-right: 10px; position: relative; padding: 1em; line-height: 1em}
ul ul {display: none; width: 150px; position:absolute; top: 2em; left: 0}
ul ul > li {float: none;}
ul > li:hover > ul,
ul > a:hover + ul {display: block}
.main {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, white, pink, orange, yellow, green);
  height: 50px;
}
ul li ul li{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, white, pink);
  height: 50px;
}
</style>
<ul class="main">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item #1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item #2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #5</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item #3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #7</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #8</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #9</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is http://jsfiddle.net/2rfvyq03/2/
[image]

Comment: This is definitely not possible unless you use a different gradient for each main menu list item.

Comment: yes, it could be done in that way, but only if menu width is fixed in pixels. In my case it is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your css

```
ul li ul li{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, white, pink,orange, yellow, green);
  height: 50px;
}
```

```css
ul > li {display: block; float: left; margin-right: 10px; position: relative; padding: 1em; line-height: 1em}
ul ul {display: none; width: 150px; position:absolute; top: 2em; left: 0}
ul ul > li {float: none;}
ul > li:hover > ul,
ul > a:hover + ul {display: block}
.main {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, white, pink, orange, yellow, green);
  height: 50px;
}
ul li ul li{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, white, pink,orange, yellow, green);
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item #1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item #2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #5</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item #3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #7</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #8</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #9</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MadhawaMB/2rfvyq03/3/

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not write the question correctly, but I want that the gradient on the sub menu was identical part from main menu.

Comment: For example when Item #1 has gradient from red to wtite, so the sub menu has the same. Next one Item #2 has gradient white->pink, so the sub menu has the same... and so on

Comment: use different class

Comment: @Maryanka im not clear you asked question, look at my 2nd answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use different class  `<ul class=sub1>` for the css you can add  to  the color for the css 
like this
`ul.sub1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, white);
  height: 150px;
}`

```css
ul > li {display: block; float: left; margin-right: 10px; position: relative; padding: 1em; line-height: 1em}
ul ul {display: none; width: 150px; position:absolute; top: 2em; left: 0}
ul ul > li {float: none;}
ul > li:hover > ul,
ul > a:hover + ul {display: block}
.main  {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, white, pink, orange, yellow, green);
  height: 50px;
}

 
 ul.sub1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, white);
  height: 150px;
}

ul.sub2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, pink, white);
  height: 150px;
}

ul.sub3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, pink,yellow);
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
  <li class="sub">
    <a href="#">Item #1</a>
    <ul class=sub1>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item #2</a>
    <ul class=sub2>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #5</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item #3</a>
    <ul class=sub3>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #7</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #8</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #9</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, this could be a solution only in case when menu has a fixed width.
Unfortunately in my case it is not

Comment: you can  write the css like this  `width:50px;`

Comment: this menu is responsive to page width, so hard-coding colors is not correct here. 
I am wondering is there any way do set for example 200px menu height and display gradient only under main menu and sub menu? Like a mask?

Comment: what are you using bootstrap?

Comment: what do you explain, can you please  explain more about it, , i can help you, im not idea what do you sayed, anyway not clear you asked question

Comment: Please take a look on a picture that I just made

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution i can come up with;

html

```
<ul class="bg">
  <li class="main">
    <a href="#">Item #1</a>
    <ul class="main">
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="main2">
    <a href="#">Item #2</a>
    <ul class="main3">
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #5</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="main3">
    <a href="#">Item #3</a>
    <ul class="main3">
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #7</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #8</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #9</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul > li {display: block; float: left; margin-right: 10px; position: relative; padding: 1em;}
ul ul {display: none; width: 150px; position:absolute; top: 2em; left: 0}
ul ul > li {float: none;}
ul > li:hover > ul,
ul > a:hover + ul {display: block}
ul li {margin:0px;}
.bg {
  background-color:orange;
  height: 50px;
}
.main {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, white);
}
.main2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white, pink);
}
.main3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, pink,orange);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2rfvyq03/5/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `background-attachment: fixed;` in the gradients of menu and submenus:

```css
ul.main{
display:flex;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.main > li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
a {
  padding: 1em;
  display: block;
}
ul ul {
  display: none;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
.main {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 0, white, pink, orange, yellow, green);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
ul li ul li {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, white, pink, orange, yellow, green);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item #1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item #2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #5</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item #3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #7</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #8</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub-Item #9</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```